Which of PHP configuration files on Linux is the 'real' one?
In the process of migrating some websites on Apache/PHP/MySQL from a Windows Server host to a Linux host, I restored them to the file system, configured virtual hosts and all of the plumbing, connected to the MySQL database, and went to log into one. After a short while it threw this error message:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1228800 bytes)

This should be a piece of cake I thought and went to change memory_limit in /etc/php.ini to 256M and bring httpd down then up. Not so fast! PHPInfo is still showing the old value:
memory_limit    128M    128M

and the app is still throwing the exactly same error as above. I double-checked that it PHPInfo is also showing the same file as the one I edited:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php.d 

Searched /etc for memory_limit and found it in 3x files: php.ini, php.ini.rpmnew and php-fpm.d/www.conf. I believe that by default Linux now runs php-fpm, so I changed the value in all the 3x of them to 256, 257, and 258M, just to be able to tell, but still PHPInfo is showing 128M after httpd stopped and restarted.
I even went into the actual web app and changed their defines for memory limit to no avail.
Where is the memory limit hiding?
